# Checkout a remote branch to view feature deployment

Tags: git, git-remote, git-checkout

I am using WP Engine's git deploy and have just completed work on a feature that I pushed to the WPE git repo for deployment to staging servers.

I would like to view those changes for various reasons like QA and client approval.

Now that my feature branch is pushed how can I switch branches only on the remote server. I don't want to clone it or download the branch in any way, just be able to view it online.

Locally, I would do `git checkout my-feature-branch` but I'm not sure on remotes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to have `feature-branch` deployed? I don't know WP Engine, but looking at the docs you can deploy with a:

```
git push production master
```

If you want to push a specific branch to WP Engine, just do:

```
git push -f production feature-branch:master
```

Be aware that this will override whatever WP Engine has on the servers as `master`.

**Note:**

If you don't have a staging environment where to try your changes and you don't want to overwrite your production, one solution is to use [feature switches](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html) and merge your changes into `master`.

In PHP you could use for example a conditional block with the new code inside, that gets activated when you pass `&feature=myfeature` as a URL parameter.

Comment: Yes, you do understand me correctly but that is not working for me. I don't want to change what is `master` I only want to switch to my `feature` on the server, the same way I can `git checkout feature` on my local machine and see the changes in my browser. `git checkout master` and everything is back to normal.

Comment: I don't think you will ever have that kind of access to WP Engine servers. You cannot remotely switch the branch that _their_ server is using to make your app run.